# Android Create Multiple User Profiles with different Preferences

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Profile Management wherein the user can have many profiles. For example there is a Profile named "Dad" which contains information about the father like his name, age and phone number which is saved using Preferences. And then the user can add another User Profile like "Mom" which contains information about the mother but with similar preferences like father but different values by clicking "Add New Profile" button.

Then on a different Activity, the user can select "Mother" or "Dad" on a spinner and the data regarding those will be displayed. This way the user won't have to change the preference every time he can just select the profile appropriate for him/her.

Comment: Not really sure what the question is?  Looks like you'd benefit from looking into - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html - or mainly sqlite

Comment: The app looks like this > [link]http://i.stack.imgur.com/2PZRC.png

Comment: Yeah, just create a DB scheme and use SQLite.  Then populate your UI using a Cursor.

Comment: I've thought of that but I'm thinking of other ways to implement it. Anyways I think I'll go for that for now until I find other ways to do it. thanks

Comment: It might not be the easiest way, but it's definitely the most organized/clean.  I guess you could also use shared preferences, but depending on how many accounts there are I could see that being kind of dirty.

Answer (score -1):

from what i understand is that you want to create like contacts list well you can use array like this`Strinig arraystring[]` and within the create new `new profile` button extend the array length :

```
int i++;
int Intarray[];
String Stringarray[];
Stringarray = new String[i];
Stringarray[i] = StringName;
Intarray[i] = new int[i];
Intarray[i] = intage;
//and save/or send the arrays using bundle
//and the array number like dad number 1 textview.setText(stringarray[1]);
```

Comment: yes i do want to create something like a contact list where I can add new contacts. thanks I'll try to work it out for a moment